# How to validate the data from postgres to mongodb

Tags: java, spring-boot, data-migration

Hi We have recently migrated the data from postgres to mongo db with some additional columns in mongo db.
We have migrated around 150M records .

Is there anyway I can validate the data ( not 150M but atleast some data) using spring boot.

Comment: This is not a suitable question for this page. Please do some research on your own first and then ask again if you're stuck. You could start improving this question by e.g. providing us with _how_ you even want to validate the records; by checking every single value to the corresponding value in the other DB? A normal job should do the trick :)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.